# Change from waterfall to agile

Tags: agile, ms-project, waterfall, business-improvement, strategy

I have been working on different kind of software projects implementation using the water fall methodology. now some of my clients want to shift to agile methodology. what do I need to take into consideration for such a change and what steps needed to start follow up with the new methodology though some client will remain working with using the waterfall way but some clients are insisting on the agile way.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: How big is your team? Is it dedicated to one client?

Answer (score 1):

A good way to think of the shift from waterfall to agile is:

Waterfall: We plan as much in advance as possible and do the work following that plan

Agile: We anticipate change happening and as a result we want to either have flexibility in our plans or we want to keep our plans short (iterations)

When your customer asks for agile delivery they mean they want to see an incremental delivery that allows them to give feedback as the work is being done.

Answer (score 0):

Agile and waterfall are not methodologies. Waterfall is a kind of project lifecycle whereas agile refers to a more general approach to organization and productivity using techniques which emphasize practices like iterative, incremental and continuous delivery, self-organizing teams, customer collaboration and responding to change.

I suggest you could start by reviewing some of the practices associated with Scrum and Kanban - two of the most popular frameworks associated with agile ways of working. https://www.agilealliance.org/agile101/

For software development frequent delivery is key. Aim to deliver working software every week or even every day, allow people to use or review it and then use their feedback to improve future iterations of the product.

Comment: Thank you @nvogel for your reply. In my situation i work on implementation of enterprise financial solutions that already developed and it require configuration, parameterization and some additional customizations to satisfy the client business need. the difficulty here is that, this kind of project used to be planned in the following way a business requirement workshop, implement the requirement , UAT acceptance ,then go live. but how to apply that to agile method. how to know that it's the time to go live with the project.